# How can I increase a number inside a while loop until my text expression gets wrong

Tags: r, while-loop, static

I need to increase a number (n) inside my while loop, but r is only doing it one time. After that it stops

I have to find the number of participants such that power is >= 0.8 with simulation. So I created a while loop and started with n=100, did a for loop to calculate the power and increased my n after that. 
given: need power of 80%
searched: sample size

```
n=100
crit.t<-qt(0.975,df=n-1)
obs_t<-c(NA,100)
power<-0

while(power<0.8){
  for (i in 1:100){
    SR<-rnorm(n,700,300)
    OR<-rnorm(n,750,300)
    obs_t[i]<-t.test(OR,SR,paired=FALSE,var.equal = TRUE)$statistic
    power<-mean(1-dnorm(n,crit.t-obs_t[i],300))
  }
n=n+1
}

print(n)
```

Expected: n=566
actual result: n=101

Answer (score 1):

I executed your code: during the first iteration (`i=1`), you get `power = 0.998`, so the while loop stop. That's why `n = 100 + 1`.

Why do you expected something else ?